# How do parental controls on the TP-Link Deco M5 work?

Tags: router, dns

I have a 4-node Deco M5 set up & working great. The kids are now getting to the age where I want to take advantage of the built in parental controls, but I can't find any explanation for how it works -- plenty of instructions on how to set it up, but that's not what I need. For example, I'm familiar with the DNS-based parental controls offered by OpenDNS & NextDNS (among others) - does this router do the same thing? Or is it using a different mechanism for blocking sites on their blacklist?

Answer (score 0):

#### Or is it using a different mechanism for blocking sites on their blacklist?

It doesn't use the OpenDNS & NextDNS blacklists.

> It’s based on blacklists compiled by the company itself.
>
> You may decide that its definition of adult content is too draconian – but you can’t whitelist sites yourself, which means the only way to grant access is to unblock all adult content.

Another issue:

> You can’t install anything on your child’s phone to stop them accessing unsuitable content if they’re connecting via mobile data. Still, it’s possible to contact your mobile operator and ask them to mark the SIM as used by an under 18.

Source: [TP-Link Deco parental controls review: Is this the perfect router for families? - The Big Tech Question](https://bigtechquestion.com/2017/11/27/review/tp-link-deco-parental-controls-review-perfect-wi-fi-choice-families/)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that link and I understand that they have their own blacklist, but does it also work by answering DNS queries for blocked sites with 0.0.0.0 (or whatever value)? Or is it a completely different (non-DNS) mechanism?

Comment: You should be able to test that by monitoring DNS queries.